# Rails3, Mongoid, cucumber. Can't set user_id field: illegal ObjectId format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, mongoid

I have an Account model:

```
class Account
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  referenced_in   :user
end
```

and User:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  ...

  references_one :account

  ...
end
```

And the following scenario(i try to set reference_one association):

```
  Scenario: Client views his account
    Given the following accounts:
      | user_id          |
      |  1123322131      |
         .....
```

And the following step:

```
Given /^the following accounts:$/ do |class_name, table|
  table.hashes.each do |attributes|
    Account.create(attributes)
  end
end
```

When I try to run cucumber, I always get an error:

```
illegal ObjectId format (BSON::InvalidObjectId)
./features/step_definitions/common_steps.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
./features/step_definitions/common_steps.rb:6:in `each'
./features/step_definitions/common_steps.rb:6:in `/^the following accounts:$/'
features/manage_accounts.feature:8:in `And the following accounts:'
```

full version of backtrace: https://gist.github.com/433ea982d876e1b1fa27

I use: Rails 3.0.3, Ruby 1.9.2, cucumber 1.9.4, machinist 2, mongoid. My [Gemfile](https://gist.github.com/c9dd8b4e8990a7e6b0a8)

What did I do wrong?

UPD. No so obviously behaviour:

```
> a = Account.create :user_id => "123" 
BSON::InvalidObjectId: illegal ObjectId format
> a = Account.create :user_id => 123
=> #<Account _id: 4ceedf055e6f991aef000005, created_at: 2010-11-25 22:11:17 UTC, updated_at: 2010-11-25 22:11:17 UTC, user_id: 123>
> a = Account.create :user_id => "4ceede9b5e6f991aef000007"
=> #<Account _id: 4ceedf1b5e6f991aef000006, created_at: 2010-11-25 22:11:39 UTC, updated_at: 2010-11-25 22:11:39 UTC, user_id: BSON::ObjectId('4ceede9b5e6f991aef000007')>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could solve your problems:

```
Given /^the following accounts:$/ do |class_name, table|
  table.hashes.each do |attributes|
    User.create(attributes).create_account
  end
end
```

Are you using a custom primary key for `User`? It seems that Mongoid is expecting a normal BSON::ObjectId like BSON::ObjectId('4ceeaf282b2d3a2ab0000001' but you are passing a plain string like 1123322131. In general, you have to be careful when trying to create a record and its associations at the same time

Comment: Yeah, you are right. See UPD. Solution is using ids like this "4ceede9b5e6f991aef000007"

Comment: I would suggest you use another field in your cucumber specs like `username` or `email` to identify your users and let Mongoid create the Object ID's for you. It's more reliable and the cucumber specs are more readable.

Comment: I tried to understand this way, it would be great, if you help me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281386/rails-cucumber-make-object-and-its-associations