# Rails, Cucumber: make object and its associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, cucumber, pickle, mongoid

I'm using [mongoid](http://mongoid.org), [machinist 2](https://github.com/notahat/machinist) and [pickle](https://github.com/ianwhite/pickle). But I think, that question is more common.

I have an Account model:

```
class Account
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  referenced_in   :user
end
```

and User:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  references_one :account
end
```

I have the following scenario(I set reference_one association):

```
  Scenario: Client views his account
    Given a user with id: "4ceede9b5e6f991aef000007"
    And the following accounts exist:
      | user_id                        |
      |  4ceede9b5e6f991aef000007      |
         .....
```

I think this is not so good idea use ids such way. What is the best practice of creating object with associations? I would be nice if pickle. for example, could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set up blueprints like this:

```
User.blueprint do
  name
  # ...
end

Account.blueprint do
  user 
  # ...
end
```

And inside cucumber:

```
Given the following accounts exist
  | user  |
  | Fred  | 
  | Ethel |
```

If pickle doesn't handle the step above, you can create your own step definition like this:

```
Given /^the following accounts:$/ do |class_name, table|
  table.hashes.each do |attributes|
    u = User.make! :name => attributes[:user]
    Account.make! :user => u
  end
end
```